# Accessing shared variables from two threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, class, shared

I'm building an application in Java which requires a Hashtable to be accessed from instances of two classes and both extend threads. I have declared the Hashtable in one of the two classes. I always get null when i try to access the Hashtable contents from one of the classes. The other class is able to access the contents without any problem. I thought this was a problem of concurrency control. Since these are threads of different classes we cannot use synchronized methods. Is there a way to make the Hashtable accessible from threads of both the classes?

Here are the some parts of the code of my application
This is the class which stores the HashMap:

```
public class DataStore {
public Map ChatWindows ;
public DataStore()
{
    ChatWindows = new ConcurrentHashMap();
}
public synchronized void putWindow(String with,ChatWindow t)
{
    ChatWindows.put(with,t);
    notifyAll();
}
public synchronized ChatWindow getWindow(String with)
{
    notifyAll();
    return (ChatWindow)ChatWindows.get(with);
}
public synchronized void ChatWindowOpen(chatClient cc,String with,String msg)
    {
       //    chatWith = with;
        ChatWindow t;
        System.out.println(with);
            t = getWindow(with);
           if(t == null)
           {
               t = new ChatWindow(cc,with,msg);
         //      th = new Thread(t);
               putWindow(with, t);
         //      th.start();
           }
           else
           {
              t.setVisible(true);

            }
}
}
```

Two classes which access 'ChatWindows' HashMap

```
public class chatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame implements 

Runnable,ListSelectionListener,MouseListener,WindowListener{

  static String LoginName,chatWith,msgToChatWindow;
    Thread listThread=null,th,chatListen;
static  Socket soc;
static  DataOutputStream dout,dout1;
static  DataInputStream din,din1;
        DefaultListModel listModel;

        ChatWindow t;

    public DataStore ds;
/** Creates new form chatClient */
public chatClient(Login l,DataStore ds) {
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    initComponents();
    clientList.addListSelectionListener(this);

     clientList.addMouseListener(this);
     addWindowListener(this);
      this.LoginName=l.loginName;

        soc = l.soc2;
        din = l.din2;
        dout = l.dout2;
        dout1 = l.dout1;
        din1 = l.din1;
        super.setTitle(LoginName);

        listThread = new Thread(this);
        listThread.start();
        this.ds = ds;

}
.
.
.
.
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
    chatWith = (String)clientList.getSelectedValue();
    ds.ChatWindowOpen(this,chatWith,"");
}
```

This class has run() method too, but that doesn't use the HashMap. This class is able to access the 'ChatWindows' properly.'ChatListenThread' class is not able to access the contents of HashMap properly.

```
public class ChatListenThread implements Runnable{

DataOutputStream dout1;
DataInputStream din1;
public static chatClient cc;
public static ChatWindow t;
public DataStore ds;
    public ChatListenThread(Login l,DataStore ds)
    {
        din1 = l.din1;
        dout1= l.dout1;
        this.ds = ds;
    }
.
.
.
.
public void run(){
   while(true)
   {
       try{
                    String msgFromServer=new String();
                    msgFromServer = din1.readUTF();
                    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(msgFromServer);
        String msgFrom=st.nextToken();
        String MsgType=st.nextToken();
                    String msg = "";
                   while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            msg=msg+" " +st.nextToken();
        }

                    ds.ChatWindowOpen(cc,msgFrom,msg);                       

       }
       catch(IOException e)
       {
            System.out.println("Read failed");

       }
   }
```

}
}

Comment: It would help if you post some relevant code snippet.

Comment: The problem is likely to be that they are not accessing the same Hashtable. There should be no problem using synchronized methods but you shouldn't need them in this case.

Comment: In each thread print the following to see if the hashtables are the same or not;  System.out.println(System.identityHashcode(myHashtable));

Comment: No the two classes are using the same HashTable. I got the same Hashcode from both the class threads

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Take a look at [Sharing data safely between two threads](http://altentee.com/2007/sharing-data-safely-between-java-threads/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what was suggested in the link. But still I am not able to access the HashMap. One of the two classes always finds the HashMap empty.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, I couldn't use your code because I don't understand, what I did see was that you want something like this:

[image: Screen shot]

1. Create a empty `JFrame` with a `JTabbedPane` and start a thread that connects to a `Socket`
2. When input comes on the socket, create a `ChatPanel` (~`JTextArea`) and add it to one of the tabs
3. Add the `ChatPanel` to  a `Map` that handles the messages from "`from`"
4. Pass the message to the newly created `ChatPanel`

So I did that and I'm posting the code below! **Hope that you can use it!**

*If you like to test this, first start the `TestChatServer` (code below) and then the `ChatSupervisor`.*

### This is the code for the client

```
public class ChatSupervisor extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
    Map<String, ChatPanel> chats = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ChatPanel>();

    public ChatSupervisor() {
        super("Test Chat");
        add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        Socket sock = null;
        try {
            sock = new Socket("localhost", 32134);

            Scanner s = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
            while (true) {

                String from = s.next();
                String type = s.next();
                String message = s.nextLine();

                getChat(from).incomingMessage(type, message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (sock != null) try { sock.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    public ChatPanel getChat(String from) {
        if (!chats.containsKey(from))
            chats.put(from, new ChatPanel(from));

        return chats.get(from);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatSupervisor cs = new ChatSupervisor();
        cs.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cs.setSize(400, 300);
        cs.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ChatPanel extends JTextArea {
        public ChatPanel(final String from) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tabs.addTab(from, ChatPanel.this);
                }
            });
        }
        public void incomingMessage(final String type, final String message) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    append("[" + type + "]" + message);
                    append("\n");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### This is the code for the test server:

```
public class TestChatServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Socket s = new ServerSocket(32134).accept();
        System.out.println("connected");
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        while (true) {

            p.println("hello info Hello World!");
            p.flush();
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                p.println("test" + i + " warn Testing for testing " + i);
                p.flush();
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the HashMap along with Collections.synchronizedMap, the problem persists.

Comment: How do you pass the `Hashtable` from one Class/Thread to the other?

Comment: I have given a snapshot of the source code of my application above. i have declared the Hashtable in Seperate class 'DataStore'.Both the classes will have a reference to it.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a chat client and a server that I just wrote... Hope that you can use it!